# How to send sms without using any button

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

How I can send message without using any button when user finish its message after 3 sec message automatically send to desire number suppose receiver number is entered here is my code.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
     String topResult = matches.get(0);
     EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextmessage);
     EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.toNumber);
     String phoneNo = null;
     String sms = null;
    switch(requestCode){
    case check1:

            editText1.setText(topResult);
            phoneNo=editText1.getText().toString();
                break;
    case check:

            editText.setText(topResult);
             sms=editText.getText().toString();

       break;
    }


    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Message Sent Successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sending fail, Please try again!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user has finished typing or closes the keyboard you could have a timer start, if the timer reaches three seconds then send the message, if the user stops the timer (re-opens the keyboard or types some more than you reset the timer back to three seconds?